# Search engine for full-text search in Django project

Tags: django, postgresql, solr, full-text-search

I'm developing full-text search function in Django project, and I'm confusing about search engine. I found haystack with elasticSearch, Whoosh, and Solr. I don't know which search engine is appropriate for my project. I'm developing st like shopping web, and I'm using postgreSql. Also, it's really nice if it can support language searching (For example: "banh my" and "bánh mỳ")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoosh is Python-based, so that is helpful if you want to stick to a single codebase.

Elasticsearch and Solr are both Java and both have Lucene core underneath. Solr is fully open-source, while Elasticsearch has commercial components. Between the two, Elasticsearch is targeted more at analytics, while Solr is stronger with searching text. But both could be tuned either way, especially for something as simple as accent folding (which seems to be your use-case).

Finally, recent versions of PostreSQL also have search engine features, which may be sufficient for your needs.